# How can I Add second NSTextAttachement image in uilabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I wanted to add image in `UILabel` along with text. However I used `NSTextAttachment` to add image at the end of `UILabel` text. I have subclass it to to fit the size of image to my text.

Now I want to add one more image in the beginning of the text, we can say as a prefix of `UILabel` (Please see the image attached).

I tried it but I do not found any good solution. can anybody please help me to get this done.

[image]

Comment: Why are you attaching image inside label? Why don't you make a UIView , and add label and UIImagView (with image inside it)?

Comment: I have tried it already but it sometimes it does not image in proper position and also using that way, everytime  I have to calculate the last character position of text in label.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your current code for inserting a `NSTextAttachment` at the end? It shouldn't be more complicated to add it at the beginning, or wherever you want in fact.

Comment: You can only add one image to your "NSTextAttachment". You can create a "UIImageView", and add it before your "UILabel"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachment it is character, you can present it as AttributedString and use it for replace some character in the string.
You can add space as first character and use *replaceCharactersInRange:* method to replace the character to attachment:

```
<...>
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" with attachments " attributes:[self attributesWithAttachment:nil]];

[attrString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withAttributedString:[self attachmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]]];
[attrString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(5, 1) withAttributedString:[self attachmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"]]];
[attrString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([attrString length] - 1, 0) withAttributedString:[self attachmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"]]];

self.label.attributedText = attrString;
<...>

- (NSAttributedString*)attachmentWithImage:(UIImage*)attachment
{
NSTextAttachment* textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithData:nil ofType:nil];
textAttachment.image = attachment;

NSAttributedString* string = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];

return string;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: can we resize the image when replacing it to character or will it keep image original size?

Comment: Anyways I managed the size with subclassing NSTextAttachement and overriding the "attachmentBoundsForTextContainer" method, thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try somethik like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
UIImageView *imgViewPrefix = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feedbackLocItemActiveIco"]];
imgViewPrefix.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

UIImageView *imgViewPostfix = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"feedbackLocItemActiveIco"]];
imgViewPostfix.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 20, 20);

label.text = @"    my text";
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[label addSubview:imgViewPrefix];
[label addSubview:imgViewPostfix];
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using a `UITableView`. For the prefix ImageView, why not use the property of the `UITableViewCell`, `imageView`?

That will simplify your solution hopefully.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView)